# Should I precautionary move callables (e.g. lambdas?)

Tags: c++, lambda, move-semantics

I have this striped-down example of a timer that I'd like to be instantiable with any kind of callable. Is it advisable to precautionary move the callable into a data member for efficiency?

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <std::invocable Cb>
class timer {
public:
    timer(Cb cb)
        : cb_ { std::move(cb) }
    {
    }

    auto call()
    {
        cb_();
    }

private:
    Cb cb_;
};

int main()
{
    std::string something_to_print = "Hello World!\n";
    timer some_timer([&]() { printf(something_to_print.c_str()); });
    some_timer.call();

    return 0;
}
```

I can't see any difference in the assembly if I move or copy the lambda. Does it ever make a difference?

Comment: An exemplary case where it makes a difference is a lambda that may be moved but not copied due to a non-copyable member. For example, having `auto l1 = [t = std::thread{}]{}`, then `auto l2 = std::move(l1);` does compile, while `auto l3 = l1;` does not. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/YdrYbejsT.

Comment: @DanielLangr That actually means you're on the save side if you move no? Fallback for non-movable types will always be copy if I'm right.

Comment: Yes, for non-movable types, trying to "move" falls back to copy (constant lvalue references can bind rvalues). But for non-copyable types, trying to "copy" results in a compilation error (rvalue references cannot bind lvalues).

Comment: @glades No, not necessarily. If for example you plan pass a lambda to several functions and the lambda has non-reference members, and is non-const, then moving it will likely break subsequent calls to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lambda has only reference captures. Moving an lvalue-reference does exactly the same as copying it. If you had `[=]` captures, the move would actually do something.

The answer to whether or not to do this in general is: "it depends on the situation." W.r.t. performance: measure.

Comment: Thx. Are lambdas generally move-enabled and std::function as well?

Comment: @glades Just look [at the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function), you'll find your answer :) (spoiler: Yes, `std::function` is moveable)

Comment: @glades To my knowledge there are no special rules for lambdas and move. They behave like any other struct/class. If you move the object, the members are moved.